# PHP pegar apenas o último <p> </p> (parágrafo)

Tags: php

Tenho um texto assim vindo do MYSQL (pode ser texto com vários parágrafos):

```
<p>Nam convallis, odio eget ullamcorper eleifend, tortor sapien.</p>
<p>Aenean quis nibh turpis. Vestibulum posuere ex.</p>
<p>In interdum auctor maximus.</p>
<p>MOSTRAR SÓ ESSE</p>
```

Eu queria dar um echo apenas no último `<p>`, como pode ser feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom consegui aqui!

```
$recebe_texto = "<p>Nam convallis, odio eget ullamcorper eleifend, tortor sapien.</p><p>Aenean quis nibh turpis. Vestibulum posuere ex.</p><p>In interdum auctor maximus.</p><p>MOSTRAR SÓ ESSE</p>";
preg_match_all('#<p>.*</p>#', $recebe_texto, $resultado);
$ultimo_paragrafo = array_pop($resultado[0]);
```